# I don't see the Cocoshap on new project xamarin.?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

In cross-platform that I just see  spriteKit Game.
How to add Cocoshap to xamarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can install Project Templates by installing an Extension. You can find [instructions on the Xamarin.Forums on how to install them](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30701/cocossharp-project-templates-for-visual-studio).

The gallery URL for Visual Studio is: `http://gallery.mobileessentials.org/feed.atom`, you will need to add that to gallery sources under **Tools > Extensions > Extensions and Updates**

Similarly for Xamarin Studio you need to install an add-on which add those templates. There are also [instructions on the Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/26822/cocossharp-project-templates-for-xamarin-studio) for that.